# Show userRoleName in navbar using Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, acl, laravel-blade

I'm new in MVC systems. I'm new user in laravel.

I have a simple problem. I read laravel documentation. But i couldn't understand MVC system exactly.

Model      : App\Models\User
Controller : App\Http\Controllers\AuthController
View       : template/navbar.blade.php

Model

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function userRole(){
        return $this->user_role;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function getLogin(){
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'mail' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if(!Auth::attempt($request->only(['mail', 'password']))){
            return redirect()->back()->with('form-error', trans('auth.failed'));
        }

            return redirect()->back()->with('info', "giriş yapıldı");
    }

    public function getLogout(){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function getRegister(){

    }

    public function postRegister(){

    }

    public function userRoleName(){

        $userRole = User::userRole();

        switch ($userRole){
            case 9: return "Üst Düzey Yönetici"; break; //superAdmin
            case 8: return "Yönetici"; break;           //admin
            case 7: return "Yardımcı Yönetici"; break;  //moderator
            case 6: return "Muhasebe Bölümü"; break;    //accounting
            case 5: return "Satış Bölümü"; break;       //marketing
            case 4: return "Depo Bölümü"; break;        //storage
            case 3: return "Ürün Yönetimi"; break;      //productManager
        }
    }
}
```

I want to show userRoleName in navbar (in views)

```
<li><a>{{ Auth::user()->name }}<br/><em>{{ -- CONTROLLER METHOD RESULT HERE --- }}</em></a></li>
```

How can i do that ? I'm using laravel 5.1

Comment: For users role use "Gate", the Laravel ACL , check this https://mattstauffer.co/blog/acl-access-control-list-authorization-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: Can OP please show us the tables used, `users` and `roles`. `Users` may have `many` `roles` and `many` `roles` can be in `many` `users`, one `user` can have one `role`, the table `users` may not have a `role_id`, the `roles` table can be related to a `user_role` table depending on the relation MN or 1N. So please enum the tables you are using. @OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function called `getUserRoleAttribute` in your User-Model like this:

```
public function getUserRoleAttribute(){
    switch ($this->user_role){
        case 9: return "Üst Düzey Yönetici"; break; //superAdmin
        case 8: return "Yönetici"; break;           //admin
        case 7: return "Yardımcı Yönetici"; break;  //moderator
        case 6: return "Muhasebe Bölümü"; break;    //accounting
        case 5: return "Satış Bölümü"; break;       //marketing
        case 4: return "Depo Bölümü"; break;        //storage
        case 3: return "Ürün Yönetimi"; break;      //productManager
    }
}
```

You can remove your other userRole-function in your model and controller entirely and just access this attribute like you access the name in your view:

```
Auth()->user()->user_role
```

This is called an accessor ([link to Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators))

Comment: thanks for your answer. But i want to learn something. I couldn't understand what is controller and what is model exactly. Models are for retreiving data from db and controllers are for rendering models. getUserRoleAttribute() is not suitiable for model am i right or i didn't understand the topic ?